Mikro-orm full-text search for Postgresql in NestJS is not able to fetch the query results
To use Full Text Search of mikro-orm in NestJS, I have set up in the entity.ts like that:
@Entity()
export class orderEnt extends base {
...
  @Property({ type: "string", nullable: true })
  invNo: string;

  @Index({ type: "fulltext" })
  @Property({
    type: FullTextType,
    onUpdate: (order: orderEnt) => order.invNo,
    nullable: true,
  })
  sInvNo: string;
...
}

Have tested the query like that service.ts:
 const resultOrders = await this.orderRepository.findAll({
      where: {
        sInvNo: { $fulltext: searchTerm },
      },
    });
 return resultOrders;
 

And this is the query log:
[query] select "o0".* from "order_ent" as "o0" where "o0"."s_inv_no" @@ plainto_tsquery('simple', '24') limit 1 [took 2 ms, 0 results]

These are package versions I'm currently using:
    "@mikro-orm/core": "^6.2.1",
    "@mikro-orm/entity-generator": "^6.2.1",
    "@mikro-orm/nestjs": "^5.2.3",
    "@mikro-orm/postgresql": "^6.2.1",
    "@mikro-orm/seeder": "^6.2.1",

What might be the issue? (OR) Am I missing something to setup elsewhere other than this?
P.S. Before full text search, this one was simple searching with $ilike and it's working well. According to the project requirements, now, this one becomes necessary to use full text search as fault tolerance search.

So you are sure the data is there? What query would you expect if this one is not working for you?

Yeah, Martin. The data are already there cos this is in ongoing project. Before using this full-text-search, this search is normal simple search using $ilike and it's working well. I'll add some background story in the post to understand more.

I am not sure if I can help much, this was a community addition, never used this myself in the wild. You could try looking at the tests and check what you do differently. https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/blob/master/tests/features/fulltext/full-text-search-tsvector.postgres.test.ts

I see. I've checked the link, and there are a lot of example use cases that can be useful. Thanks, Martin. Will take a ref. on it.
